# How to replace all periods in a string that aren't in an html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to replace all periods in a user submitted paragraph of text that will most likely be copy and pasted from a microsoft word document so the text will have formatting on it.

For example, text pasted in from word looks like this:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-bottom: 5.75pt; text-indent: 0.5in;"><span style="font-size:12.0pt;font-family: etc...
```

I need to edit all of the periods not within these tags and put span tags around them, so I can't just grab the html and do .replace.

:(

Answer (score 0):

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery) to find text nodes, then do the replace on them.

If you have it as a string, convert into document fragment first.